# How can I get my menu to be on the same line as my logo

Tags: html, css

I am creating a header with a logo and CSS menu. I want them to be both on the same line, and when I did this, I used

```
#header img, #header ul{
display:inline-block;
}
```

When I was using a custom menu I made, this worked fine. However, I decided to use a CSS menu generator to design a nicer looking menu. This broke it, and I am not sure what the problem is.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYMfv/)

I also noticed that in the jsFiddle, my hover color for the links is not working. It works fine locally so I'm assuming this is either a jsFiddle issue or I forgot to upload something. But I just copied and pasted the whole thing so I'm not sure what that would be. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/KYMfv/1/)

Try add padding to header, change inline-block to inline and remove width:

```
#header {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
}
```

to show at bottom [Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/KYMfv/2/):

```
#header {
    text-align:center;

    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:150px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    width:100%;
}
#header img, #header ul{
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Another good answer, but my follow up question is, how can I get that menu down to the bottom of the header?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 100%; display: block` from your `.menu`.

```
/* Generated via www.cssmenubuilder.com */

.menu{margin:0 auto; padding:0; height:30px; background:url('images/topMenuImages.png') repeat-x;}
```

To position your menu at the bottom add the following:

```
#header { position: relative; }

.menu { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYMfv/3/)

Comment: This was a great answer. Will accept when possible. Could you also show me how to put my menu down to the bottom of the header? Here is an screenshot of what is going on [link](https://imageshack.com/i/1nxdz4p)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't view your image from your code, so I'm not sure what is exactly you wanted. But I made this simple code to make the logo and menu on the same line, whereby the menu is aligned in the middle of the height of logo/header. You can check the fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sJZx5/)

```
.header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu{
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 100px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.menu li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```